# Ошибка при записи в файл csv

Tags: python, pandas, requests, beautiful-soup, bs4

```
import requests
import pandas
from time import sleep

data = []


def page_one():
    url = 'https://www.olx.ua/d/uk/nedvizhimost/komnaty/dolgosrochnaya-arenda-komnat/poltava/'
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    sleep(3)
    name_info = soup.find_all('h6', class_='css-v3vynn-Text eu5v0x0')
    for info in name_info:
        data.append(info.text)
    price = soup.find_all("p", class_='css-wpfvmn-Text eu5v0x0')
    for p in price:
        data.append(p.text)


def all_pages():
    for page in range(2, 3):
        sleep(3)
        print(page)
        url1 = f'https://www.olx.ua/d/uk/nedvizhimost/komnaty/dolgosrochnaya-arenda-komnat/poltava/?page={page}'
        r = requests.get(url1)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

        name_info = soup.find_all('h6', class_='css-v3vynn-Text eu5v0x0')
        for info in name_info:
            data.append(info.text)
        price = soup.find_all("p", class_='css-wpfvmn-Text eu5v0x0')
        for p in price:
            data.append(p.text)


page_one()
all_pages()
df = pandas.DataFrame([data], columns=["Name", "Price"])
df.to_csv('test.csv', sep=";")
```

Ошибка:

````
2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\shifu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 982, in _finalize_columns_and_data
    columns = _validate_or_indexify_columns(contents, columns)
  File "C:\Users\shifu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 1030, in _validate_or_indexify_columns
    raise AssertionError(
AssertionError: 2 columns passed, passed data had 106 columns


Process finished with exit code 1```
````

Answer (score 0):

```
from time import sleep
import pandas
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = []

def all_pages():
    for page in range(1, 3):
        sleep(3)
        url1 = f'https://www.olx.ua/d/uk/nedvizhimost/komnaty/dolgosrochnaya-arenda-komnat/poltava/?page={page}'
        r = requests.get(url1)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
        info = soup.find_all('div', class_='css-19ucd76')
        for fo in info:
            name = fo.find('h6')
            price = fo.find("p")
            if name:
               data.append([name.text, price.text])

all_pages()
df = pandas.DataFrame(data, columns=["Name", "Price"])
df.to_csv('test.csv', sep=";")
print(df)

                                                Name                Price
0                            Аренда комнаты в Полтаве           2 500 грн.
1                              Сдам комнату в Полтаве           4 000 грн.
.....
53                                   Здам койко-місце             800 грн.
54  Временно,возьму на кв.девушку заочницу,команди...           1 950 грн.
```